# Why does image exceeds parent container when max-width/height is set to 100%?

Tags: html, css

Its a thing that have bugged me for quite a while; as far as I understand, the `width` and `height` is relative to its most-inner parent e.g setting `max-width` and `max-height` should not allow any object in the container to exceed the parent.

For some reason, this happens to my image using the following css:

```css
.main-product{
height:50vh;
background-color: #fff;
border: 0.05rem solid #e4e4e4;
position: relative;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.image-wrap{
background-color: #4c7bf1;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 75%;
height: 60%;
margin-top:0.5rem;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-wrap img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

and the html

```html
<div class="main-product">

          <div class="image-wrap">

            <figure>
              <img src="{{p.image_url}}">
            </figure>
          </div>
    </div>
```

can some one explain, why some (images) exceed the parent when `max-width` and/or `max-height` is set to (or less than) 100%?

Comment: You hadn't define a height to your img wrapper. If you add `.image-wrap figure { height: 100%; }` it will work as expected.

Comment: height is defined in `image-wrapper` (60%)

Comment: But it's not defined for the direct parent of the image. Your img tag has `max-height: 100%`, it means max-height: 100% of the parent's height, but the parent's height isn't defined.

Comment: It still overflows

Comment: You have few options
1: remove figure element if not required
2: Add width: 100%; height:100% for figure element